# How to effciently recent media with one button

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

Currently I have it setup like so. The problem is that when I go to play the media again it plays a little bit of where it left off before returning to the start.

```
bsharks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {     
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (sharks.isPlaying()) {
            sharks.seekTo(0); 
            sharks.pause(); 
        }
        else { 
            sharks.start();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As I can see, you are pausing the mediaplayer, not resetting it. So, If you want to play it from start, Then do a little change like below :

```
bsharks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (sharks.isPlaying()) {
            sharks.reset();  

        }
        else { 
            sharks.prepare();
            sharks.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**seekTo()** is an asynchronous call, meaning that once called, it will immediately return, and as per documentation:

> **seekTo(int)** call returns right way, the actual seek operation may take a while to finish, especially for audio/video being streamed. When the actual seek operation completes, the internal player engine calls a user supplied OnSeekComplete.onSeekComplete() if an OnSeekCompleteListener has been registered beforehand via setOnSeekCompleteListener(OnSeekCompleteListener).

Also, **pause()** behaves in a similar way:

> When the call to **pause()** returns, the MediaPlayer object enters the Paused state. Note that the transition from the Started state to the Paused state and vice versa happens asynchronously in the player engine. It may take some time before the state is updated in calls to isPlaying(), and it can be a number of seconds in the case of streamed content.

What you could do is to register onSeekComplete() listener, then set a flag, say boolean canPlay = false and change it to true once onSeekComplete() fires. Then in your onClick():

```
bsharks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (sharks.isPlaying()) {
            sharks.seekTo(0); 
            sharks.pause(); 
        }
        else { 
            if (canPlay) {
                canPlay = false;
                sharks.start();
            }
    }
}
```

Please read more about MediaPlayer state machine [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html).